# Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^2 -> \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transform such that   $$T(\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1
  \end{bmatrix}
) = \begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    1\\
    1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
 and 
$$T(\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    2
  \end{bmatrix}
)
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    3\\
    1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Find 
$$T(
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0
  \end{bmatrix}
)
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\pmatrix{1\\0} = 2 \pmatrix{1\\1} - \pmatrix{1\\2}
$$

Comment: I got a 3x1 matrix with elements {3, -1, 1}. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct.